# error while using python 3.6 and opencv-python cv2

Tags: python, camera, face-recognition, opencv

Error in using python open cv to initialize the camera in a face recognition task

```
import cv2
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
camera.grab()
ret, frame = camera.retrieve()
cv2.namedWindow('frame')
```

.

```
OpenCV: out device of bound (0-0): 1
OpenCV: camera failed to properly initialize!
```

Comment: in my laptop camera has number `0`. Did you try other numbers ?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that I'm not using an extra webcam and my pc has just one camera, so this line should be: 
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

Comment: You'd think that, but sometimes the order of USB enumeration is surprising. Try 0. `lsusb` might provide some evidence, if you have it installed.